# How to activate checkbox inside a Dropdown with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I check the checkbox inside a dropdown menu with Python Selenium?

Within a list I have many checkboxes. I would like to activate the checkboxes that I pass through the code, but I have not been able to achieve it.

This is the structure of the web page, I can't see the `selector Id` for the checkbox, only I can see it the `data-value` or the text value name `Texto1`, `Texto2`, `Texto3`, etc.

[Image](https://ibb.co/SsxxYSk)

So my question is how can I check the checkbox with the data-value or text name?

I'm using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(50)
driver.get('http://midominio.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
driver.find_element_by_id("dropdownMenu2").click()
```

Comment: There is no `dropdownMenu2` id

Comment: yes, but this is a drop-down menu in this drop-down menu there are all the check box and here I don't now how check these checkbox. @vitaliis

Comment: Add a page which you test, main page does not have such elements

Comment: I do not know what you mean, sorry, the web field is not what I master. Can you be more precise on your idea, please? @vitaliis

Comment: I do not see the element you are looking for here http://midominio.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click first checkbox use:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#Plants00>li:nth-of-type(1)>a>input").click()
```

Second:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#Plants00>li:nth-of-type(2)>a>input").click()
```

Also remove duplication of `implicitly_wait`. YOu do not really need it.

Comment: You are welcome. Next time when posting a question if possible add an actual page. It will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath like //*[text()='Texto1'] to select the checkbox